# How can I print all of the documents in a document library using code?

Tags: 2007, document-library, printing

I want to know how to print all the files in a document library. I googled it and unable to find the solution. But during search I [found a tool](http://www.sharepointprinting.com/) which provides almost the same type of functionality.

Please guide me. How can I achieve this type of functionality?

Comment: Basant Did you find any solution for this? If yes, Please share with me.

Comment: Any solution to this question yet? I am in dire need of this. Worried coder.

Comment: @Basant B. Pandey and Kit Menke please guys can you share the solution with us ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem. I copied the files from a temp folder and using JavaScript I was able to print the files using Microsoft OneNote 2010.

Answer (score 0):

I basically map a network drive to the location (i.e. turn http://it-etp.xyzcorp.com/sites/abcdept/ to \it-etp.xyzcorp.com\sites\abcdept\, browse to it, and map a drive to the location (mapping a drive is optional, but helpful in SharePoint management in the long run). There are many ways to perform the next steps, but basically I open my "Printers and Faxes" and open the destination printer I want. I then open the browser that I mapped the SharePoint site in, select the files, and then drag / drop them onto the printer. You will likely get a message letting you know that you will be printing multiple documents, but I disregard those and let the system work away (it may take quite a while depending on the number of docs you wish to print).

Answer (score -1):

I would try to make a print css file. 
Add a link to the page (masterpage) and open the current page in a new window, loading the print CSS.

Off-course you could always add a dropdown button using code, but you still need to make the print css.

Comment: @Jan - print CSS is not going to help here - a document library contains... well documents such as Excel/Word/PDF etc. Applying a print CSS is not going to do anything to help.