# How can I print all documents in a libaray?

Tags: 2010, document-library, printing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How Can I Print SharePoint document Library Documents Using code?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/4104/how-can-i-print-sharepoint-document-library-documents-using-code)

I found this question:  [How can I print all of the documents in a document library using code?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/4104/how-can-i-print-sharepoint-document-library-documents-using-code)  but it does not appear to have a solution.

I would be interested in doing this using code.  Can anyone point me to a starting point?

Comment: Anyone out there?